# How to specify location of files on a RAID disk for website hosted on Mac OS X

Tags: raid, mac-osx

So, I am hosting a website on a Mac Pro. The website links to a couple of files which are located on a RAID attached to the Mac Pro. (Let's call this RAID1)

Also, there is another RAIDs attached to the Mac Pro (let's call it RAID2)

If I want to change the location of these files from RAID1 to RAID2, how do I change the path in the website? The HTML links do not specify RAID1 or RAID2 in their path

Comment: You don't. You specify the path to the location on the volume/partition where the files reside.

Comment: You change the document root in your web server.